# SQL Query in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

Anybody know why the geoserver does not implement a direct sql query when setup a layer?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the format of the Geoloc db field type?  If the database were a  upgrade from an older sql server that didn't have geocode data types, then by having a newer sql server implement a view, then the old data need no change??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developers just hadn't gotten around to it yet.  (There is not a huge need for this feature since GeoServer can serve a database view as easily as a table.)  However, now GeoServer is able to dynamically alter the SQL used to fetch feature data from databases.  This functionality is discussed in the GeoServer users manual at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: since I wrote this response the feature has been documented in the geoserver manual.  I'll update the link to point at that, thanks for letting me know it was broken @djangofan .